# Get section index of clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my website I need to get the index of a clicked elements section.

There is one `<div>` with multiple `<section>` and each one has a `<ul>`.
Each sections has own, unique section headers.

If you click a list element the class turns from `listFUTItem has-auction-data` to `listFUTItem has-auction-data active` (tried to rebuild that at the playground).

At the `<div>` only one list element can be active at once. (Not working at this snipped but at the website)

At the moment my code works like this:
`itemList =  document.querySelectorAll('.sectioned-item-list > ul')[2]`
But the index has to be variable.

```js
$('.listFUTItem').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().filter('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('listFUTItem has-auction-data active');
  console.log( $('.listFUTItem.has-auction-data').index(this) );
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #00FF00;
}
.ut-section-header-view {
    padding: .75rem .5rem;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.listFUTitem {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transferlist" style="height: calc(100% - 2.5rem); width: calc(100% - 350px);">
<section class="sectioned-item-list>
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Unsold Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
<section class="sectioned-item-list>
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Sold Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
</div>
<section class="sectioned-item-list>
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Available Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
</div>
<section class="sectioned-item-list>
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Unsold Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `closest()` to traverse up to the `<section>` and get it's index within the collection of all the sections of that class

```js
const $sections = $('.sectioned-item-list');

$('.listFUTItem').click(function() {     
  const $sect  = $(this).closest('.sectioned-item-list'); 
  const sectIndex = $sections.index($sect);
  console.log(sectIndex)
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #00FF00;
}
.ut-section-header-view {
    padding: .75rem .5rem;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.listFUTitem {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transferlist" style="height: calc(100% - 2.5rem); width: calc(100% - 350px);">
<section class="sectioned-item-list">
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Unsold Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
<section class="sectioned-item-list">
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Sold Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
</div>
<section class="sectioned-item-list">
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Available Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
</div>
<section class="sectioned-item-list">
<header class="ut-section-header-view">
<h2>Unsold Items</h2>
</header>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jQuery` [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) for this. Use `$('.transferlist section ul li.active').removeClass('active')` to remove `.active` class from all *active* list items. Run the following snippet to check the outcome:

```
$(this).index();
```

against

```
$(".listFUTItem.has-auction-data").index(this);
```

```js
$('.listFUTItem').click(function() {
  $('.transferlist section ul li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('listFUTItem has-auction-data active');
  console.clear();
  console.log('$(this).index() value is ->\t' + $(this).index());
  console.log('$(this).parents("section").index() value is ->\t' + $(this).parents("section").index());
  console.log('$(".listFUTItem.has-auction-data").index(this) value is ->\t' + $('.listFUTItem.has-auction-data').index(this));

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #00FF00;
}

.ut-section-header-view {
  padding: .75rem .5rem;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.listFUTitem {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transferlist" style="height: calc(100% - 2.5rem); width: calc(100% - 350px);">
  <section class="sectioned-item-list">
    <header class="ut-section-header-view">
      <h2>Unsold Items</h2>
    </header>
    <ul class="paginated ">
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Ballack</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Lehmann</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Pique</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Kroos</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Owen</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="sectioned-item-list">
    <header class="ut-section-header-view">
      <h2>Sold Items</h2>
    </header>
    <ul class="paginated">
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="sectioned-item-list">
    <header class="ut-section-header-view">
      <h2>Available Items</h2>
    </header>
    <ul class="paginated ">
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Ballack</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Lehmann</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Pique</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Kroos</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data "> Owen</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="sectioned-item-list">
    <header class="ut-section-header-view">
      <h2>Unsold Items</h2>
    </header>
    <ul class="paginated">
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
      <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```